# JQuery set value to custom made server control

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

We have a custom made server control which several properties defined in it.

```
<cc1:DropdownCheck ID="ddcStatus"  runat="server" CssClass="ddlchklst" JQueryURL="~/Scripts/jquery.js"
                    Title="Select Status(es)" OpenOnStart="false" divHeight="17px" 
                ImageURL="Images/DropDown.PNG" >
            </cc1:DropdownCheck>
```

How can I set the value of the Title property on a click event of the server control. My current jquery fn looks like this...

```
$("#ddcStatus").click(function () {
            //$('#ddcStatus').attr("Title",'Items Selected');
            //document.getElementById("ddcStatus").Title = 'Items Selected';
        });
```

Both statements didnt work. The getElementById statement gave a script error saying object null.

Comment: What's the rendered html output of this custom control? This title property is a custom property displayed in a div or span? post the rendered html.

Comment: Check how the element is rendered in the browser. Code has to be written based on it

Comment: It worked after I re-wrote the query based on the rendered HTML. The title was shown as a div so i had to read the text property of the div! Thanks Ritik & Sushanth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in your selector
"#ddcStatus" is use to select element with id ddcStatus but it is not same at clint side.
You Wil see it something like "abc_xzy_ddcStatus"

ID get changed when page load at client side. so you have two option to solve it

1. In browser go to source code by selecting view source or by inspect element and find
   new ID in source and use that ID in jQuery
   (I don't recommend this way)
2. use something called dynamic selector  which server ID and convert to Client ID by self

$('DropdownCheck[ID$="ddcStatus"]')

you can read this as "select in DropdownCheck whose id ends with ddStatus"

**Your solution will not be same replace DropdownCheck with actual control used at client side**
some help for start with and end with style of jquery

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/#attributevalue

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like that:

```
$(function(){
    $("#ddcStatus").click(function () {
        //$('#ddcStatus').attr("Title",'Items Selected');
        //document.getElementById("ddcStatus").Title = 'Items Selected';
    });
})
```